# What is it homeomorphic to?

Tags: general-topology

Today a friend of mine did me the following question. Could you help me to understand what is it homeomorphic to?

Considering in $\mathbb{E^2}$ the following topologycal subspace:

$$X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x=0\text{ or }x=1 \}$$

Let it be $ \sim $ the following equivalence relation:

$$(0,y_1) \sim (1,y_2) \leftrightarrow y_2-y_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

What is $X/{\sim}$ homeomorphic to?

Is the answer $\mathbb{S^1} \times \mathbb{S^1}$?

Comment: Is $E^{2}$ = ( $R^2$,d) where d is the usual metric in 2 dimensional real space? We usually don't distinguish between the field $R^2$ and the metric space $E^2$ in practice.

Comment: Some day I might start to suspect that there are people to whom the difference between $\displaystyle\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|x=0\text{ or }x=1 \}$ and $\displaystyle\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x=0\text{ or }x=1 \}$ is not conspicuous and distracting.  I changed it.  Also, I changed $X/\sim$ to $X/{\sim}$.  The former has extra space because it's treating $\sim$ as a binary relation symbol.  In _this_ instance, it's not being used in an expression of the form $a\sim b$, so the extra space that would usually be appropriate is not. Just enclosing it in braces does the job. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 : Could you write $E^2=(R^2,d)$ instead of $E^2$ = ($R^2$,d)?  That is standard and proper TeX usage.  Since your profile says you're a mathematics graduate student, you will want to get used to LaTeX. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\mathbb{E}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidian topology

Comment: @MichaelHardy I can't believe that makes a difference,the size of the parentheses. I know we have to be clear and precise here-but really? I don't understand the TeX notation difference.

Comment: It makes the fonts and sizes of characters match and results in proper spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(0,y) \sim (1,y)$ for all $y$, since $y - y = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.  So you can "glue" these two lines together, and instead consider the space $Y = \mathbb{R}$ under the equivalence $a \sim b \iff a - b \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Can you recognize this quotient space?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. So is it $\mathbb{S^1}$?

Comment: Yep! ${} {} {} {}$

Comment: Bingo. : ) And it's really interesting since it's a very counterintuitive example.